# How to build a comparison and update function of tables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to build a comparison function between an old and an new version of a table. The single constant is the amound and name of columns. The amount of rows may change when new entries appear in the new version of the table. The output should be a updated table, where new entries are taken as additinonal rows and deleted entries should remain in the table and labled as "inactive" in a for this purpose created column (the new entries labled as "new"). There might be changes of a single entry in a row. For this the row should be updated and the changed value should be "old value + new value" and the row should be labled as "edited".

I need to use pandas for this purpose and had some try's with `merge(frame_old, frame_new, how='outer', indicator=True)`. Here I generate the status column (containing "new", "edited" and  "inactive") automatically -> `_merged`. But naturally there is no functionalities for recognizing edited entries ...

Because it is easier to explain the function with a example I prepared one:

**Table old**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

dict_old= {
           'ID' : ["IQL_000", "SID_002", "OLA_056"],
           'Text' : ["foo", "hello", "a descirption"],
           'Number' : ["0991", "1231", "333"]
          }
frame_old= pd.DataFrame(dict_old)
```

**Table new**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

dict_new= {
           'ID' : ["IQL_000", "SID_002", "PPA_344"],
           'Text' : ["foo", "world", "nothing"],
           'Number' : ["0991", "1231", "978"]
          }
frame_new= pd.DataFrame(dict_new)
```

**Table updated**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

dict_updated= {
               'ID' : ["IQL_000", "SID_002", "OLA_056", "PPA_344"],
               'Text' : ["foo", "OLD:hello, NEW:world", "a descirption", "nothing"],
               'Number' : ["0991", "1231", "333", "978"],
               'Status' : ["active", "edited", "inactive", "new"]
          }
frame_updated= pd.DataFrame(dict_updated)
```

Comment: If you specify `on="ID"` during the merge, you would receive two `Text` columns which you can compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `pandas.merge` to merge the old and new tables.
2. `groupby` on the "ID" column and use custom `agg` functions.
3. Assign the required "Status" using `map`.

```
frame_old = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ["IQL_000", "SID_002", "OLA_056"],'Text' : ["foo", "hello", "a descirption"],'Number' : ["0991", "1231", "333"]})
frame_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ["IQL_000", "SID_002", "PPA_344"], 'Text' : ["foo", "world", "nothing"], 'Number' : ["0991", "1231", "978"]})

merged = pd.merge(frame_old, frame_new, indicator=True, how="outer", suffixes=("_old", "_new"))
output = merged.groupby("ID").agg({"Text": lambda x: f"OLD: {x.iat[0]} NEW: {x.iat[-1]}" if len(x.unique())>1 else x, 
                                   "Number": lambda x: f"OLD: {x.iat[0]} NEW: {x.iat[-1]}" if len(x.unique())>1 else x.iat[-1], 
                                   "_merge": lambda x: x if len(x.unique())==1 else "edited"})

output["Status"] = output["_merge"].map({"left_only": "inactive",
                                         "right_only": "new", 
                                         "both": "active", 
                                         "edited": "edited"})
output = output[["Text", "Number", "Status"]].reset_index()

>>> output
        ID                   Text Number    Status
0  IQL_000                    foo   0991    active
1  OLA_056          a descirption    333  inactive
2  PPA_344                nothing    978       new
3  SID_002  OLD: hello NEW: world   1231    edited
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Although no value in Number was changed, a change in this column is also possible. When I apply the same lambda function for Numer instead of ```"last"``` I get the following output for the edited row: ```3  SID_002  OLD: hello NEW: world     []    edited```. Note: I didn't changed any Number yet.

Answer (score 1):

From your `DataFrames`, we can start by apply a `merge` on them (here we show the indicator to be sure about the data origin) :

```py
>>> frame_merged = frame_old.merge(frame_new, how='outer', indicator=True)
>>> frame_merged
    ID      Text            Number  _merge
0   IQL_000 foo             0991    both
1   SID_002 hello           1231    left_only
2   OLA_056 a descirption   333     left_only
3   SID_002 world           1231    right_only
4   PPA_344 nothing         978     right_only
```

Then, using a `groupby` applied to `list`, we got the expected result, knowing that the last element of the list is the current value :

```py
>>> frame_text = frame_merged.groupby(['ID'])['Text'].apply(list).reset_index()
>>> frame_text
    ID      Number  Text
0   IQL_000 0991    [foo]
1   OLA_056 333     [a descirption]
2   PPA_344 978     [nothing]
3   SID_002 1231    [hello, world]
```

For the `Status` column, we can apply a similar strategy using the `_merge` column generated earlier :

```py
>>> frame_edited = frame_merged.groupby(['ID', 'Number'])['_merge'].apply(list).reset_index()
>>> frame_edited['_merge'] = frame_edited['_merge'].astype(str)
>>> frame_edited
ID  Number          _merge
0   IQL_000 0991    ['both']
1   OLA_056 333     ['left_only']
2   PPA_344 978     ['right_only']
3   SID_002 1231    ['left_only', 'right_only']
```

Then, we can use `numpy` to rewrite the wanted `Status` :

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> condlist = [frame_edited['_merge'] == "['both']", 
...             frame_edited['_merge'] == "['left_only']", 
...             frame_edited['_merge'] == "['right_only']",
...             frame_edited['_merge'] == "['left_only', 'right_only']",]
>>> choicelist = ['active',
...               'inactive',
...               'new', 
...               'edited']            
>>> frame_edited['Status'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
>>> frame_edited = frame_edited.drop(['_merge'], axis=1)
>>> frame_edited
    ID      Number  Status
0   IQL_000 0991    active
1   OLA_056 333     inactive
2   PPA_344 978     new
3   SID_002 1231    edited
```

To get the expected result, we can merge those two `DataFrames` like so :

```py
>>> pd.merge(frame_merged, frame_edited, how="inner", left_on=['ID', 'Number'], right_on=['ID', 'Number'])
    ID      Number  Text            Status
0   IQL_000 0991    [foo]           active
1   OLA_056 333     [a descirption] inactive
2   PPA_344 978     [nothing]       new
3   SID_002 1231    [hello, world]  edited
```

To add the `OLD/NEW` labels, we can use the following function :

```py
def add_prefixe(row):
   if len(row['Text']) == 2:
       return ["OLD:" + row['Text'][0],  "NEW:" + row["Text"][1]]
   else:
       return row['Text']

df = df.assign(Text = df.apply(add_prefixe, axis=1))
```

Then we finally obtain :

```py
>>> df
    ID      Number  Text                        Status
0   IQL_000 0991    [foo]                       active
1   OLA_056 333     [a descirption]             inactive
2   PPA_344 978     [nothing]                   new
3   SID_002 1231    [OLD:hello, NEW:world]      edited
```

Comment: That's incorrect. In the row at index 2, "nothing" is the new value but the first list element

Comment: Indeed, I corrected my answer. Thanks @not_speshal !

Comment: The result is still the same

Comment: I precised that the last element of the list is the current value. I am going to add the "old/new" label to avoid any confusion.